# How to pass variable value from php to external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a value sitting in my database which i want to use in an external JavaScript file. The JavaScript file is being referenced in the the html code using `<script src="/thanks/thanks.js"></script>` 
Can anyone please help to figure out how i can either pass the value from php tp JavaScript or how i can access the database from the JavaScript?

Comment: can you at least try something (google may be your friend, or any other reference about php/javascript) ? Stackoverflow purpose is not to code something for you...

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use the `<script>` tag and echo the value you want to.

```
<?php
    echo "<script>var parse = $value;</script>";
?>
```

Now you can use your value in javascript (parse variable). But if you want to have it detailed...
here is the duplicate you didnt search for: [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)